# Ascending a String input of numbers in java

Tags: java, arrays, string, sorting

I am working on a program where user can input random numbers and when user give -1 the loop will break and the entered numbers will be displayed

```
  Example:
  Enter a Number: 32

  Enter next Number: 1243

  Enter next Number: 123

  Enter next Number: 76

  Enter next Number: -1

  Thank You. You have entered 32, 1243, 123, 76
```

Now whatever number is entered it will be displayed in ascending order

```
 ----Ascending order -----
   [32,76,123,1243]
```

Now i have completed the following but the to get exact result the user need  to enter

```
 ->0032

 ->0076

 ->0123

 ->1243
```

Then i am getting the exact result

```
    [0032, 0076, 0123, 1234]
```

Then only my sorting is working fine otherwise it is like

```
      [ 123, 1243, 32, 72]
```

Now how to solve this ?

```
package Testx;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test7Ctr{

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner user = new Scanner(System.in);
    String user_input = "";
    String holdv="";
    String holdvx="";   
    String ascend="";
    //AsveNd(user_input);

try
{
    int b =0;

    do
    {
        System.out.print("Enter next number:");
        user_input = user.nextLine();
        int x= Integer.valueOf(user_input);

        if (x != -1)
        {
        holdv=user_input;
        holdvx+=holdv+",";
        ascend+=holdv+" ";
        b++;
        }

        else
        {

            System.out.println("THANK YOU FOR ENTERING= "+holdvx);
            break;
        }
    }
   while(b <= 100);
    {

    }

    String[] numbers=ascend.split("\\s");
    for(String numb:numbers)
    {  
        int intarray[] = new int[numbers.length]; 
        Arrays.sort(numbers);
        //break;
        }  
    System.out.println("---Ascending order---");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers));

}
catch(Exception e)
{

}

}
}
```

Comment: well you are storing your `numbers` as Strings, so when you sort you will do sorting by String not int - what is the use of `intarray` it is not even used

Comment: I would also recommend, for learning purposes, that you submit your working code on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/. Empty catch clauses, wrong casing, bad variable names... ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the proper integer sorting with the following:

```
String[] numbers = ascend.split("\\s");
int intarray[] = new int[numbers.length];
int i = 0;
for (String numb : numbers)
{
    // convert the String to an int
    intarray[i++] = Integer.parseInt(numb);
}
Arrays.sort(intarray); // sort the int array, not the String array
System.out.println("---Ascending order---");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(intarray));
```

**Side Note**:

Your do/while loop would be better written as:

```
int x = 0;
do
{
    System.out.print("Enter next number:");
    user_input = user.nextLine();
    x = Integer.valueOf(user_input);

    if (x != -1)
    {
        holdv = user_input;
        holdvx += holdv + ",";
        ascend += holdv + " ";
    }

} while (x != -1);

System.out.println("THANK YOU FOR ENTERING= " + holdvx);
```

- You don't need the `int b`
- You don't need the else statement in the loop. Just have the loop terminate when x is -1.
- Also, you had an empty block after the `while (...);` That is not doing anything. The while portion of a do/while loop has no body.

Answer (score 3):

**You are sorting strings rather than numbers.** This makes your sort work in lexicographic order instead of plain ascending order.
So to fix your problem, simply add `Integer`s and not `String`s. You can even parse a `String` to an `Integer` using `Integer.parseInt()`.

Also, there is no need to call `sort` every time you insert a new number, but just once in the end. That adds a lot of overhead to your process.

Answer (score 0):

You are sorting the "Strings" and not the "numbers". Scan those inputs as number, put them to a dynamic list (and not a static sized array) and then sort the list of numbers (and not of string)